# «Ekzistas» kiel traduko de «there is» / «il y a»

Tags: word-usage

Kiam mi komencis studi Esperanton mi lernis ke oni diras «estas» kiel tradukon de la angla «there is/are» aŭ la franca «il y a». Tamen, lastetempe mi ofte aŭdas «ekzistas» uzatan en tiu senco. Ekzemple, povas esti frazoj kiel la jenaj:

> Ekzistas vespermanĝo por vi en la fridujo.
>
> Ĉu ekzistas uzantoj de [Amikumu](https://amikumu.com/eo/) en Antartiko?

Por mi tiu vortumo ŝajnas stranga. Ŝajnas al mi ke estas nuanca diferenco inter la signifoj de *estas* kaj *ekzistas*, kaj *ekzistas* pli taŭgus en frazoj kiel la jena:

> Ĉu vi sciis ke ekzistas specio de vespo kiu demetas siajn ovojn en figojn?

Ĉu oni povus diri ke la uzo en la unuaj du ekzemploj estas erara? Aŭ ĉu ĝi estas evoluo de la lingvo, aŭ ĉu mi simple malbone komprenas la vorton?

Answer (score 6):

Por esprimi ĉeeston oni daŭre uzas kaj uzu *estas*. La vorto *ekzisti* estas tre emfaza (laŭ [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#ekzisti) "efektive kaj nune esti"), kaj almenaŭ en la unua ekzemplo ĝi laŭ mi estas klare erara.

Tamen mi ne certas pri la dua ekzemplo, ĝi povus esti lima okazo tre substrekita *esti*, do en la senco "ĉu **entute** estas **iaj** uzantoj".
Tia uzo ŝajne ne estas Zamenhofa, sed troviĝas jam ĉe Kabe: "ekzistas urbanoj, kiuj neniam vidis kamparon".