# Ĉu "esti" aŭ "ekzisti"?

Tags: translation, word-usage, verbs

Duolingo tradukas l'anglan frazon "There are seven days in one week." al "*Estas sep tagoj en unu semajno.*"

Kial Duo ne uzas la verbon "Ekzistas", anstataŭ "Estas"?

Comment: Please see this related question: https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/3199/ekzistas-kiel-traduko-de-there-is-il-y-a/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PIV donas la difinojn kaj ekzemplojn

- [**ekzisti**](http://vortaro.net/#ekzisti) efektive k nune esti

Ne kredas ŝtelisto, ke honestaj ekzistas.

Kie lumo ekzistas, ankaŭ ombro troviĝas.

- [**esti**](http://vortaro.net/#esti)

1 verbo esprimanta la ekziston

Mi pensas, do mi estas.

Dio diris: estu lumo.

Ne estas facile esprimi la malsamecon. La verbo "esti" ĝenerale esprimas ekziston, kontraŭe al la verbo "ekzisti", kiu emfazas, ke iu aŭ io ekzistas ĝuste nun, dum la tempo, kiun la verbotempo esprimas.

Ne misgvidiĝu per la angla esprimo "There are…", kiu ne rilatas al la malsameco inter "ekzisti" kaj "esti", sed rolas kiel formala subjekto, kiun oni bezonas en la angla, ne en Esperanto.

Antaŭ longe oni decidis, ke [semajno nuntempe havas sep tagoj](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semajno), do estas ĝenerale konata, ke semajno havas tiom multe da tagoj: *"Estas sep tagoj en unu semajno."*

Comment: Dankegon Sinjoro Metsäkallas pro via helpo.